# Where SQLite DB is stored in Desktop after it is created

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created a SQLite Database in Xamarin forms with below code in Visual Studio 2017.

```
try
            {
                sqliteconnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
                sqliteconnection.CreateTable<MyClassModel>();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string strErr = ex.ToString();
            }
```

in Xamarin.Android:

```
public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            // Documents folder  
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, DatabaseHelper.DbFileName);
            var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path);

            // Return the database connection  
            return conn;
        }
```

I have added data into table.  How can I get the Database out to check if there are data.

I use this method: C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local on my PC to check.

But Cannot find the Database.

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but creating that will not put a file in that path

Comment: I deploy Xamarin forms app from VS2017 to Droid phone. Wil the above code create a DB in Droid phone and a Copy of DB in Desktop for VS2017? Where Can I find the DB created.

Comment: This code is run from the phone, so any `GetFolderPath` will return a value on the phone, not on your PC.

Comment: In this case where and how I can get a copy of the SQLite DB created  in Droid Phone? Is the above code OK?

Comment: ```System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal``` this folder is something else. If you want to save it where you looked for it ```LocalApplicationData``` should be the one not ```Personal```. But  I'd say print or log or debug the paths and you'll see where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite Database is stored on the *phone* and not on your *pc.* If your phone is not rooted, you cannot directly access it. To access it on your phone, you have to get root access, then the databse can be found under ***data/data//files/.***

To view the database schema, you can pull the database off the device and use a SQLite manager tool to view the schema and browse the data. One easy way to do this is to launch the application in the Android emulator. While the emulator is still running, open the Android SDK Command prompt. There is a shortcut to launch this in Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio from the Tools menu. At the command prompt, **type: *adb pull [full path and database file name].***

You can get the path when debugging the application by checking the Path property on the SQLiteDatabase object.

> *Example :*
>   **adb pull /data/data/< Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/< your-database-name>**

The database will be copied to the Android SDK folder on your machine. To view the SQLite database that was copied to your machine, you can use a tool like ***DB Browser for SQLite: http://sqlitebrowser.org*** if you are using Visual Studio, you can install the ***SQLite Toolbox extension*** which you can work with from within your Visual Studio IDE to manage your SQLite database: ***http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/***.

Comment: How get root access to view data/data//files/ ? I m at lost! I look at Android SDK folder  in Program files(x86) which folder to look?